# How to implement plugin stealth in Puppeteer Sharp?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, puppeteer, sharp

I would like to know how and if it is possible to use `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth` inside of visual studio project.
As far as I read there is a project called: `puppeteer sharp` but they didn't showed how to use the plugin stealth, as this is best browser which is not detectable as a "`bot`".

In my other `puppeteer .js file` compiled by `Docker` I have this code to load installed `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`:

**Docker puppeteer code:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const stealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const { IS_PROD } = require('../utils/constants');

puppeteer.use(stealthPlugin());

// In order to run chromium processes in parallel. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/594#issuecomment-325919885
process.setMaxListeners(Infinity);

const getBrowserInstance = async (port) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: IS_PROD ? ['--no-sandbox', `--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:${port}`] : ['--no-sandbox'],
    devtools: !IS_PROD,
    executablePath: IS_PROD ? '/usr/bin/chromium-browser' : undefined,
  });
  const incognitoBrowserContext = browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  incognitoBrowserContext.close = browser.close;
  return incognitoBrowserContext;
};

module.exports = {
  getBrowserInstance,
};
```

BUT THIS is my C# Form where I don't know how to use or load or implement `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`

**My VS Code:**

```
using PuppeteerSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace pupe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = true
            });
            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            await page.SetViewportAsync(new ViewPortOptions
            {
                Width = 1920,
                Height = 1080
            });
            await page.GoToAsync("https://bot.sannysoft.com/");
            await page.ScreenshotAsync("screens/test.png", new ScreenshotOptions { Type = ScreenshotType.Png });
           
            MessageBox.Show("screen done!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding the stealth plugin to puppeteer-sharp may not be as simple than on the NodeJS Version. A C# port of the puppeteer-extra which works with puppeteersharp exists. Check https://github.com/Overmiind/Puppeteer-sharp-extra.

Comment: Please, avoid link as the answer and explain in your own words what is exactly requested (and add link at the end for more info or reference). Thanks!

Comment: Tested this, and it works!